# Getting a word after a certain character?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make myself a program that will take a String and give me the word after a certain character. So, for example:

```
String theString = "hello \t world"; // or "borld \t bello";
```

After the tab, I only want "world" and not "hello." This keeps crashing on me for some reason.

```
size_t delimiter = theString.find_last_of('\t');
char *test;

if (theString.find("hello") != string::npos) {
     strcpy(test, theString.substr(delimiter + 1).c_str());
else if (theString.find("borld") != string::npos) {
     strcpy(test, theString.substr(delimiter + 1).c_str());
}

cout << test;
```

Comment: _"This keeps crashing on me for some reason."_ No wonder, you never allocate space for `char *test;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `strcpy` manual:

`char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);`

> The strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src, including
>          the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed to by dest.

In your code, you declare `test` as a pointer to `char*` but you never initialize it.

`test` is therefore a pointer to indeterminate value. You then attempt to copy data to that inderminate location, resulting in the crash.

You can fix this easily by initializing `test` to point to memory you can `strcpy` to. Be sure to allow enough to not write beyond the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

always the same mistake why you write to test without initializing it?

```
char *test; // no memory allocated so using it will cause a segfault
char test[50]; // just for explaining we allocate 50 bytes for pointer test
// char* test = new char[50]; // the same above but here dynamic memory
// delete[] test; // free up memory because dynamic memory is not automatically freed
```